# Set a C-style array with template function accepting callback

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

So, let's say I'm writing a function to set an array using a user-supplied callback per item.  (I'm not, but let's suppose I am, for the purposes of a *minimal* example)

The cleanest way I can find to do this is the following:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T, typename Y>
void PopulateArray(std::function<int(Y*)> callback, T &pArray)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(pArray); ++i)
    int x = callback(&pArray[i]);
}

int main()
{
  uint64_t myArray[5];
  uint64_t myUint = 42;
  PopulateArray( (std::function<int(uint64_t*)>) [=](auto x) {*x = myUint; return 0; },
    myArray);
}
```

I have two issues with the code above.

1) For `T` to be an array type, there seems to be no way to modify the parameter.  (I can't say I want an *array* of type `T`, meaning I have to declare `Y` separately, even though they are both related to `uint64_t`.)  I would prefer to declare a single `T`, with one parameter being a pointer to `T` and the other being an array of `T`.

2)  The client code (in main), is forced to cast the lambda.  Changing `auto x` to an explicit type doesn't seem to help matters.

Is there a resolution to #1 or #2 that might make the code more succinct or readable?

Code will need to compile with gcc, clang, and VS.  I *think* C++11 is the newest standard I can use, although I'd be interested in C++14 solutions, as that would be a matter of upgrading our clang build process.  I'm not interested in solutions that involve switching myArray to `std::array` `std::vector`, etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the requirement for `std::function`:

```
// You could consider using an array type for the parameter:
// template <typename Callback, typename T, std::size_t N>
// void PopulateArray(Callback callback, T (&pArray)[N])
template<typename Callback, typename T>
void PopulateArray(Callback callback, T& pArray)
{
  // sizeof(pArray) as in the question is almost certainly not what you 
  // want. It returns the size *in bytes*, not the length of the array.
  // Thus, if you specified this to take an array reference,
  // `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)` would be correct.

  // However, as Barry mentioned in the comments, a range-based for loop
  // is the best solution.
  for (T& element : pArray)
    callback(&element);
}

int main()
{
  std::uint64_t myArray[5];
  PopulateArray([](auto x) {*x = 42; return 0; },
    myArray);
}
```

`std::function` is an expensive type. It uses virtual function calls (or techniques that are very similar) and has the potential to allocate memory. If you are not storing the function and especially if the function is already a template, just take an arbitrary callback as your parameter. If you really want to constrain the callback's type, use a `function_ref` type (not yet standardized), or check that `callback(your, args)` is valid:

```
template<typename Callback, typename T>
auto PopulateArray(Callback callback, T& pArray)
    -> decltype(callback(*std::begin(pArray)), void())
{
  for (T& element : pArray)
    callback(&element);
}
```

---

Also, in this specific case, you can use [an algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm):

```
int main()
{
  uint64_t myArray[5];
  uint64_t myUint = 42;
  // If it's all the same value:
  std::fill(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), myUint);
  // To call a function to populate the array:
  std::generate(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), [myUint] {
    return myUint;
  });
  // Or possibly:
  std::for_each(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray),
    [myUint](uint64_t& element) {
      element = myUint;
    });
}
```

Comment: I adjusted my question slightly to reflect a requirement I forgot (captures), but your  answer still seems to work.  Also, thank you on the `sizeof` comment.  Brain malfunction there, but I'm sure it would've cost me at least an hour.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you.  This answer helped me more than several re-reads of relevant chapters of `Effective Modern C++` (the array thing is specifically mentioned, but I didn't quite connect the dots.)

Comment: This answer helped make this possible: `1 file changed, 1610 insertions(+), 4788 deletions(-)`

Comment: Would suggest `for (T& e : pArray) { callback(&e); }`, side-step any looping issues at all. If you didn't have to pass a pointer, would even say `for_each(begin(pArray), end(pArray), callback);`

Comment: @Barry Good point. I tend to forget that C-style arrays work with range-based things

Comment: Appreciate the additional suggestions.  Long story short, the single-value thing was just stub code (the actual callbacks are longish msgpack functions) to present the real problem, which your initial response solved beautifully.

Comment: Re the looping "PopulateArray" is a thin wrapper around a template function that takes explicit sizes for the benefit of other clients with already decayed array pointers. :) My life is hard and savage.